# Conflito entre jquery.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou com conflito entre o

```
<script src="assets/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

e os

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

alguém sabe alguma forma de resolver?ambos são existenciais

Comment: Por curiosidade, por que necessita de versões distintas?

Comment: a mais recente controla os gráficos, tabelas... basicamente a estrutura do projeto e os mais antigos controlam meu input autocomplete.

Comment: Não seria o caso de criar um componente autocomplete com uma versão mais atualizada e assim deixar suas bibliotecas sempre atualizadas? É mais viável que alterar todas as tabelas, gráficos, etc.

Answer (score 7):

O jQuery possui a função `jQuery.noConflict` para contornar erros de conflito. Ela foi, originalmente, feita para resolver conflitos com outras bibliotecas que também definem o objeto `$`, mas pode ser usado para utilizar múltiplas versões do jQuery.

```
<script src="assets/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const $jQ3_3_1 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
    const $jQ1_12_4 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Ou seja, assim que você adiciona o jQuery 3.3.1 você utiliza a função `noConflict` para criar a instância em `$jQ3_3_1`, bem como depois que você adiciona o jQuery 1.12.4 você utiliza novamente para criar a instância `$jQ1_12_4`, usando cada instância onde necessitar.

Porém isso provavelmente é desnecessário. Usar jQuery em uma aplicação hoje já é questionável; usar duas é mais ainda. Não vale a pena adicionar todo o *payload* que a biblioteca exige apenas para utilizar uma *feature*. Se é um *plugin* que necessita, recomendo que busque algo atualizado e utilize apenas uma das versões na aplicação.